# Spring MVC eliminate *.html pattern

Tags: spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC 3.1 with following front controller configuration:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>paymentSystemServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>paymentSystemServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Because I have pattern like "*.html" I have to do next thing. I need an html extension in all my url's to controller (e.g. 'a href=/admin.html' intercepts controller with request mapping '/admin'). Can I configure some url-pattern in order to avoid html extensions in my url? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By mapping DispatcherServlet to /, you can use it as a default servlet and it’ll be responsible for handling all requests including html, htm etc.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or you can use the Spring MVC 3.x [default servlet handler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) to do the job. Just add that following to the Spring XML config.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: Thank you, slashdot. Every internal pages works fine now but I have my start page is /login and earlier when I have my <welcome-file-list> like /login.html I attempt enter my app by say http://localhost:8080/ it redirected me to login page fine. Now when I attempt to enter that kind I have 404 error (and I need to enter manualy by http://localhost:8080/login)

Comment: Tomcat requires that index.html actually exists on the file-system, otherwise it sends a 404 response for requests to /. Do you have the following listed in your config:                                <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

Comment: I solved this issue by map one of my start controllers to '/' path. Thank you

Comment: I would like to vote up you but it requires 15 points of reputation which I don't have :( When I reach 15 points I will vote you up mandatory.